# Is medical expense of a guest injury tax deductible?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction

A guest was hurt in my party. I paid his medical bill. Is this expense deductible in the U.S.? If so, where does it go on 1040 Schedule A?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unless the guest is your spouse or dependent. From the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc502.html):

> If you itemize your deductions for a taxable year on Form 1040,
>   Schedule A (PDF), Itemized Deductions, you may be able to deduct
>   expenses you paid that year for medical and dental care for **yourself,
>   your spouse, and your dependents**.